# Google Maps .getCenter method

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, geometry

Does anyone know how I can get the `lat` and the `lng` as separate variables using the Google Maps API `.getCenter()` method

For example, I call the following line of code to get the centre of a circle on a map:

```
var circle_centre=selector_circle.getCenter();
```

The above works fine. Is there a way to get the `lat` and `lng` as separate variables instead of them both being contained within the one variable, `circle_centre`? I have researched it and can't seem to find an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It returns a LatLng object. To get the lat call circle_centre.lat(), to get the lng call circle_centre.lng()

```
var lat = circle_centre.lat();
var lng = circle_centre.lng();
```